# Calculating the color temperature and intensity of skylight with an algorithm

Tags: visible-light

I think it will be possible to calculate the natural sky light intensity and color balance (CCT) based on time of day/year, GPS location. Has anyone seen a formula/algorithm for this? I would like to work this out for an app that will present the values in 15 minute increments. Eg: 12 noon, November , tropical north coast Australia CCT in deg Kelvin = 5600 deg, Light intensity 32000 LUX. If anyone knows how to calculate this please chime in. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is highly possible that you are wrong

Comment: I did something very similar for my MSc, what you are missing from your explanation are other factors - e.g. clouds (visible and subvisible) and aerosols among others.

Comment: Thank you Ghost, indeed Cloud data would need to be added as a variable EG, cloud base and height. That would be the next challenge. I can scrape the BOM.GOV.AU server for the current cloud data to add this variable, a clean output from the algorithm presenting basic CCT and LUX with a clear blue sky is somewhere to start. I am searching for this formula. Thanks in advance if you could help.

Comment: Aerosols would be a major variable (as I found when I did my MSc, based in Tokyo).

Comment: Yes , I spent 3 years in Tokyo, indeed the CCT was skewed to the red when the angle of the sun was low and intensity was decreased . The ceilometer data can provide this variable with the accuracy I am hoping to achieve. Any ideas on how to create a algorithm would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of algorithmic sky models. see for instance paper (and previous work section) https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00288758

But this is not related at all to "color temperature", i.e. Plank's law (or black body). (well, there is the Sun's one at the begining, but after it's about selective absorption, Rayleigh and Mie (multiple) scattering, etc).

Comment: Thank you Fabrice.. Do you know of a measurement other than Kelvin to represent the CCT colour balance of skylight. I come from a filming/lighting background therefore that is the only measurement I am familiar with.

Comment: Kelvin color truely makes sense only for thermal-sources of light, like the Sun or incandescent light. I'm not sure how this is extended to mean something for other light sources, e.g. mades of emissive bands or selective scattering.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET The CCT -- correlated color temperature is an anthropocentric measurement of light sources. It is basically how hot something looks like for the human retina, pretending that it's black body radiation.